# Problems with conversion in Berkeley DB in Java project

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I using Berkeley DB in my project. In the process of refactoring I moved class (which is field of UserEntity class) to another directory. DB throw error "Mutation is missing to evolve class: Role version 0. Class not found". The problem is that Role class is an Enum, that couldn't be versioned. I trying convert UserEntity: add converter at startup of DB, run app, but without Role.class in previous directory i got an error, and with it no conversion. What should I do with this?

Comment: Is it in a different package and needs to be included?

Comment: @NomadMaker, it is different module. I want to merge two modules in one and delete "old" module